# HTML/CSS change drop down nav to menu on top right of header

Tags: css, menu, position, nav, display

I am trying to use media queries so that above 500px my nav is displayed as just the 3 items in the menu class on the top right header section (no background).

The hamburger nav is working perfectly below 500px, but above it is getting stuck on the left side of the page and it will not display in-line or even change background colour.

Any advice?

The Live page is hosted [here](https://megdollar.github.io/Clarity/).  And the repo is [here](https://github.com/megdollar/Clarity/tree/gh-pages).

Comment: The code that changes the nav is located in responsive.css

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Explicitly add the particular section of code outside media query */

div#nav{
   background-color : #dddddd;
   width : 100%;
  }
  div#nav *{ 
   display : inline-block;
  }
 
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
 div#nav{
   background-color : #dddddd;
   width : 100%;
  }
  div#nav *{ 
   display : inline-block;
  }
 }
```

```html
<div id="nav">
      
          <nav class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#" class="menu">Why Clarity</a>
              <p class="divider"> | </p>
              <a href="#" class="menu">Benefits</a>
              <p class="divider"> | </p>
              <a href="#" class="menu">Diversity</a>
          </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sort of works, the nav is still displaying block over 500px, and its on the left side instead of the right. Since I have a lot of styling going on in the regular css file style.css i want to be able to change it in the media query